# How to check if an app payment charge was declined on Shopify?

Tags: shopify

I'm trying to not allow users access to my app if they decline the payment charge. How do I check what 'state' shop is in after a charge has been accepted or declined?

This from Shopify api doc

> After the charge has been accepted or declined, Shopify redirects the
>   shop owner to the return_url set in the request. At this point the
>   **shop is either in an accepted or declined state**. In order to actually
>   receive payment for this charge it must be activated by your
>   application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check the charge status. It will be accepted or declined.

eg:

```
charge = ShopifyAPI::ApplicationCharge.find(params[:charge_id])
puts charge.status == 'accepted' ? "accepted" : "declined or other"
```

or

```
charge = ShopifyAPI::RecurringApplicationCharge.find(params[:charge_id])
puts charge.status == 'accepted' ? "accepted" : "declined or other"
```